# How to run below PL/SQL code from groovy againts oracle database

Tags: oracle, groovy

Below is PL/SQL code I want to run from groovy program against oracle database.

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Employee';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

How can I get that. I have every thing setup like connecting to oracle database from my groovy program.
I want to do it somthing like below:

```
sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)
String plSql="BEGIN\n" +
        "   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Employee';\n" +
        "EXCEPTION\n" +
        "   WHEN OTHERS THEN\n" +
        "      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN\n" +
        "         RAISE;\n" +
        "      END IF;\n" +
        "END;\n" +
        "/"

sql.execute(plSql)
```

Error log-from comments

Below is error I am getting...

```
Jun 29, 2015 9:05:52 PM groovy.sql.Sql execute WARNING: Failed to execute: BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Employee'; EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN RAISE; END IF; END; / because: ORA-06550: line 9, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored. Caught: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 9, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored
```

Comment: Did you try running the program? What happens?

Comment: Below is error I am getting...

Jun 29, 2015 9:05:52 PM groovy.sql.Sql execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Employee';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/ because: ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.

Caught: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.

Comment: As the error suggests, remove the ending "/" which isn't needed via a direct API call but only when run as a script.

Comment: @Mukesh Singh : please edit question to include more details. I edited your question and moved the info from comments.  Please check SO faq.  If the below answer was useful, accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the call method to execute a PL/SQL block.
As mentioned above do not add slash, but use the terminating semicolon.

```
groovyCon.call("""BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Employee';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;""")
```

Additionally you may profit from the Groovy multiline  string (""") which allowes direct cut and paste of the PL/SQL block between database and Groovy.