# Soapui test step groovy script to call stored procedure and return results

Tags: stored-procedures, groovy, soapui

I'm using soapui5.1.3 groovy script test step to execute a MS SQL stored procedure "find" with begin, end and id parameters as inputs for stored procedure.

Below is my syntax, I want to print all the rows with column name  "empName". But when I execute below syntax getting result value as 0.

Can anyone please help with right syntax?

```
def result = sql.call("{call find @begin = '01/01/2016 10:00' @end = '01/02/2016 10:00', @id = '1'}")
log.info(result)
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119400/how-to-run-below-pl-sql-code-from-groovy-againts-oracle-database) link to see if that helps.

Comment: @ahs can you share your stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
def rowsAffected = sql.call("{call find('01/01/2016 10:00','01/02/2016 10:00','1')}")
println rowsAffected
```

Or alternatively passing the parameters:

```
def rowsAffected = sql.call("{call find(?,?,?)}",['01/01/2016 10:00','01/02/2016 10:00','1'])
println rowsAffected
```

However if you want to get some result instead of only see the affected rows you can do it:

```
 sql.call("{? = call find(?,?,?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, '01/01/2016 10:00','01/02/2016 10:00','1'], 
 { empName->
     println empName
 })
```

In this last sample note that the *first element* in the params array is the type of your return variable, I suppose that it's a `VARCHAR` but change accordingly if your `PROCEDURE` returns a different type.

Take a look at [`groovy.sql.Sql` API](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#call(groovy.lang.GString)) since there are good sample for [`Sql.call` methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#call(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

**NOTE:** To use it with *SOAPUI* remember to put your DB vendor specific libraries in `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` folder and then restart *SOAPUI* in order to load the DB *.jar*.